# Filler in BoxLayout.yLast()?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to add a lead button over 2 components which are sometimes separated by an empty space as they are in a container which layout is set to BoxLayout.Y_AXIS_BOTTOM_LAST. I want to be able to trigger the button by tapping in the empty space between the component. How can I create a filler component which will take just the leftover available place, if any? I am also interested in other approaches.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's problematic as the layout literally doesn't leave anything there. You have two options I can think of:

- Create your own layout manager and follow the logic to place a button there if applicable
- Add a pointer released listener to the form and look at the coordinates pressed. If the form isn't scrollable (not filled yet) and the pointer event comes in a y coordinate that's larger than the absoluteY + height of the before last button yet smaller than the absoluteY of the last button then this is a click in the right location

I'm guessing that what you want is the latter. If you want to draw something there you can use a bgPainter on the parent container style that will draw information there.